# Public page access with Azure AD on Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory

I got the marching orders to apply Azure Active Directory to an existing WebForms c# site which has 2 public facing pages. I was able to integrate the site with Azure AD using owin packages and configuring the app in Azure. The single sign-in is working as expected.

The problem I'm having is getting the public facing pages to allow anonymous access. I'm used to data annotations such as `[AllowAnonymous]` in MVC but I'm not sure of a good approach to implement something like that in Web Forms.

I've already tried placing the public aspx pages in a public folder along with this web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In order to use:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You need to have Anonymous Authentication enabled for the project in the properties window in Visual Studio. Just editing the csproj file alone won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/849113/four-easy-steps-to-set-up-owin-for-form-authentica

basically for web forms apps, you set it in the configuration sections of the web.config files in either root, or etc. , you tell it which paths require what auth, which don't, etc. 
as per the above link, something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="About.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
 </configuration>
```

so this basically says deny all anonymous users for the about.aspx page. meaning the equivalent of [authorize] in mvc

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out the issue was Anonymous Authentication was set to Disabled in the project properties.